# Git create release on commit reading a variable in file

Tags: php, git, github, automation

I have a PHP project,
with a file called `release.php`, that's just containing some info about the version of the project and a variable `$create_release`:

```
<?php
$release = '1.0.4';
$release_date = '2019/05/30';
$create_release = TRUE;
```

I would on git push to GitHub, create a release if the variable inside PHP file is set TRUE.

How can I trigger GitHub release creation automatically on git push?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK GitHub doesn't support standard git hooks. It exposes [Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) thou. I'd integrate it with some endpoint on your side.

In other words, you're pushing to GitHub. Webhook is fired and calls your endpoint. Your endpoint inspects the change and fires release process if all requirements are met.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tomtit](https://github.com/melezhik/tomtit) task manager as well for that type of tasks. Just create this helper inside PWD:

**.tomtit/push.pl6**

```
#!perl6

task-run "push my changes", "git-push";

if slurp "release.php" ~~ / '$' create_release \s+ '=' \s+ TRUE / {
  bash "./fire-release.sh" # or whatever command you need 
}
```

Then just:

```
tom push
```